# Angular control for inputting latitude and longitude with validation

Tags: validation, typescript, geospatial, angular-2+, unit-conversion

I've built a custom control to handle user input in a human-readable format, but save in a machine-format.
It needs to have input validation, and to convert UI-input to a base format.

I'm interested in knowing:

- Have I implemented this in a proper and idiomatic Angular way?
- Are there any UI and typescript mistakes?
- Have I missed anything in the implementation?
- Is there a better way to implement this sort of behaviour?

---

In this case, the custom control is used to input latitudes and longitudes in "degree minute decimal-seconds" (47° 22' 0.4959"N) and save them in "decimal degrees" (47.366804405489006).

Each degree (°) can be broken into 60 minutes ('). Each minute can be divided into 60 seconds (").

---

## Main code

### coordinate-input.component.html

```html
<input #box
       [placeholder]="placeholder"
       (blur)="triggerLostFocus()"
       (change)="triggerInputChange(box.value)" />
```

### coordinate-input.component.scss

```css
:host {
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

### coordinate-input.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, Renderer2, ViewChild, ElementRef, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { degreesToDMS, dmsToDegrees, DmsParseResult } from 'app/services/utils';
import { GeographicPositionType } from 'app/models/position';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

// This component was built following guidelines/instructions from:
// https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73
@Component({
  selector: 'aby-coordinate-input',
  templateUrl: './coordinate-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coordinate-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CoordinateInputComponent),
    multi: true,
  }, {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CoordinateInputComponent),
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class CoordinateInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator  {
  @Input()
  public type: GeographicPositionType;
  @Input()
  public placeholder: string = null;
  @Input()
  public debug: boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('box')
  private inputElem: ElementRef;
  protected _value: number;
  protected _valueHumanized: string;
  public lastEdition: string;
  private parseResult: DmsParseResult = null;

  // The method used to emit changes back to the form.
  private propagateUiValueChanged = (_: any) => { };
  private propagateTouched = (_: any) => { };
  private validatorInputsChanged = (_: any) => { };

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private translator: TranslateService,
  ) {
  }

  triggerInputChange(newValue: string) {
    this.checkForChanges(newValue);
  }

  triggerLostFocus() {
    this.propagateTouched(true);
  }

  private checkForChanges(edit: string): void {
    if (this.lastEdition === edit) {
      return;
    }

    const result: DmsParseResult = dmsToDegrees(edit, this.type, this.translator);
    this.parseResult = result;
    if (result.success) {
      this._value = result.parsedValue;
      this._valueHumanized = edit;
    }
    this.lastEdition = edit;
    this.propagateUiValueChanged(this._value);
    this.validatorInputsChanged(this._value);
  }

  // --- BEGIN: Validator: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator ---
  // "Method that performs synchronous validation against the provided control."
  validate(_control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    if (this.parseResult == null || this.parseResult.success) {
      return null;
    }
    return {
      parse: this.parseResult.errorMessage,
    };
  }
  // "Registers a callback function to call when the validator inputs change."
  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.validatorInputsChanged = fn;
  }
  // --- END: Validator ---

  // --- BEGIN: ControlValueAccessor: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor ---

  /**
   * Writes a new value to the element.
   * @param obj The new value for the element
   */
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    const newUserValue = degreesToDMS(obj, this.type);
    this._value = obj;
    // Push value to UI; it will be received back in the callbacks.
    this.inputElem.nativeElement.value = newUserValue;
    this._valueHumanized = newUserValue;
    this.lastEdition = newUserValue;
    this.parseResult = null;
  }
  /**
   * Registers a callback function that is called when the control's value changes in the UI.
   * @param fn The callback function to register.
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateUiValueChanged = fn;
  }
  /**
   * Registers a callback function that is called by the forms API on initialization to update the form model on blur.
   * @param fn The callback function to register.
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateTouched = fn;
  }
  /**
   * Function that is called by the forms API when the control status changes to or from 'DISABLED'.
   * Depending on the status, it enables or disables the appropriate DOM element.
   * @param isDisabled The disabled status to set on the element.
   */
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // Disable the UI.
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.inputElem.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }
  // --- END: ControlValueAccessor ---
}
```

## Supporting code

### position.ts

```js
export enum GeographicPositionType {
  Latitude = 'Latitude',
  Longitude = 'Longitude',
}
```

### utils.ts

```js
import { GeographicPositionType } from 'app/models/position';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export const directionFromSignal = (decimalDegrees: number, positionType: GeographicPositionType): string => {
  switch (positionType) {
    case GeographicPositionType.Latitude:
      return decimalDegrees >= 0 ? 'N' : 'S';
    case GeographicPositionType.Longitude:
      return decimalDegrees >= 0 ? 'E' : 'W';
    default:
      throw new TypeError('Unknown geographic position type.');
  }
};

export const degreesToDMS = (decimalDegrees: number, positionType: GeographicPositionType): string => {
  if (decimalDegrees == null || Number.isNaN(decimalDegrees) || !Number.isFinite(decimalDegrees)) {
    return null;
  }

  const direction: string = directionFromSignal(decimalDegrees, positionType);

  // We need to make this absolute, or when rounding negative numbers,
  // it rounds down and all the math gets incorrect.
  const decimalDegreesAbs = Math.abs(decimalDegrees);

  let degrees = Math.floor(decimalDegreesAbs);
  const decimalMinutes = (decimalDegreesAbs - degrees) * 60;
  let minutes = Math.floor(decimalMinutes);
  let decimalSeconds = (decimalMinutes - minutes) * 60;

  // After rounding the seconds and the minutes might become 60,
  // so we need to account for that.

  // NOTE: we check against 59.9999 because toLocaleString rounds the value,
  // so 59.9999 turns into 60. But rounding before decimalSeconds would mean
  // any value above 59.5 would be considered 60, which we don't want.
  if (decimalSeconds >= 59.9999) {
    minutes++;
    decimalSeconds = 0;
  }
  if (minutes === 60) {
    degrees++;
    minutes = 0;
  }

  const seconds: string = decimalSeconds.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    useGrouping: false, // Specifies whether to use grouping separators.
    minimumFractionDigits: 4,
    maximumFractionDigits: 4,
  });

  // 1° 2' 3.4567"N
  return `${degrees}° ${minutes}' ${seconds}"${direction}`;
};

export interface DmsParseResult {
    success: boolean;
    parsedValue: number;
    errorMessage: string;
}

const parsedOk = (value: number): DmsParseResult => {
  return {
    success: true,
    errorMessage: null,
    parsedValue: value,
  };
};

const parseError = (translator: TranslateService, reason: string, interpolateParams?: Object): DmsParseResult => {
  const translated: string = translator.instant('coordinateConversions.' + reason, interpolateParams);
  return {
    success: false,
    errorMessage: translated,
    parsedValue: null,
  };
};

const dmsRegex: RegExp = /^(\d+)°(\d+)'(\d+\.?\d*)"(\w)$/;

export const normalizeDmsString = (input: string): string => {
  if (input == null) {
    return input;
  }
  let normalized = input;
  normalized = normalized.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  normalized = normalized.replace(/º/g, '°');
  normalized = normalized.replace(/´|‘|’|′/g, '\'');
  normalized = normalized.replace(/''|“|”|″/g, '"');
  return normalized;
};

const handleCleanMatch = (
  translator: TranslateService,
  degrees: number,
  minutes: number,
  decimalSeconds: number,
  signal: string,
  positionType: GeographicPositionType,
  ): DmsParseResult => {
  const value = degrees + minutes / 60 + decimalSeconds / 3600;

  switch (positionType) {
    case GeographicPositionType.Latitude:
      switch (signal) {
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
          return parsedOk(value);
        case 'S':
        case 's':
          return parsedOk(-value);
        default:
          return parseError(translator, 'Signal symbol "{{signal}}" should be N or S.', {signal: signal});
      }
    case GeographicPositionType.Longitude:
      switch (signal) {
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
          return parsedOk(value);
        case 'W':
        case 'w':
          return parsedOk(-value);
        default:
          return parseError(translator, 'Signal symbol "{{signal}}" should be E or W.', {signal: signal});
      }
    default:
      throw new TypeError('Unknown geographic position type.');
  }
};

export const dmsToDegrees = (humanReadable: string, positionType: GeographicPositionType, translator: TranslateService): DmsParseResult => {
  if (humanReadable == null) {
    return parsedOk(null);
  }

  const normalized = normalizeDmsString(humanReadable);
  if (normalized === '') {
    return parsedOk(null);
  }

  const match: RegExpMatchArray = normalized.match(dmsRegex);
  if (match !== null && match.length === 5) {
    const degrees = Number(match[1]);
    const minutes = Number(match[2]);
    const decimalSeconds = Number(match[3]);
    const signal = match[4];

    return handleCleanMatch(translator, degrees, minutes, decimalSeconds, signal, positionType);
  }

  const sampleSignal = positionType === GeographicPositionType.Latitude ? 'N' : 'W';
  return parseError(translator, 'Input must be in format: 12° 34\' 56.789"{{signal}}', {signal: sampleSignal});
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A short review;

- Changing CSS for `input` seems too broad, just apply CSS changes to a class tied to your control
- `throw new TypeError('Unknown geographic position type.');` seems odd, why throw this if the calling function does not catch it anyway? You need a think on how this control handles exceptions.
- Similarly, in `degreesToDMS` you return `null` , but the calling functions don't deal with returned `null` values. You need a think about that as well.
- Naming is well done
- Commenting is well done
- Design seems standard to me for a new control

Comment: Thank you for your time! :) In Angular, component CSS is scoped to the component itself; it never affects neither parent nor children HTML elements. The error is thrown for code-completion; it is never expected to happen, unless some idiot developer (me) forgets to set the type or sets it wrongly; and then an error will be visibly thrown in the console. The null in `degreesToDms` is passed directly to the UI; the input will have an empty string, which IMO is correct according to an empty or invalid latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 2):

In additions to [konijn's remarks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/231151/207526) I would add some other that I would normally add reviewing this code.

**Explicit type declarations**

In the following code there is no need to declare type:

```
public debug: boolean = false;
```

The TypeScritpt compiler will understand the type from the assigned value.

**Methods with side effects**

You have a method `checkForChanges(edit: string)`. It is not obvious from the method name that it produces side effects (changes the component's state). I would suggest you to rename the method to make it clear. Maybe `propagateChanges`?

**Fields/variables naming**

It is probably a matter of taste, but I would suggest you to use names starting with the underscore sign (`_value`) as less as possible. The only valid case I know is when you want to have [a getter with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167446/2065796), but it is not the case here.

**Use of `any` declarations**

Try to use `any` as less as possible. TypeScript encourages types and Angular framework is designed in the way that you need `any` only in case you interact with third party JS libs.

Comment: Thank you for your time. :) I like my types explicit, as much as possible. About the any, I only know the specific type in `write()`; in the other places, I couldn't figure out what type would be correct (or even if I am meant to pick a type myself); do you have suggestions of idiomatic types, or how I could find out the expected types in e.g. the `registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { }` method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't invest much time going deep into the implementation, maybe there is no other way. As for `registerOnTouched` [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) declares it as `any`.

Comment: <shrug> Such is life. Thanks for the doc link. :)